# kestrel running in docker can't serve static content

Tags: docker, .net-core

I built a docker image using the generated template:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

and then created a docker-compose to host the kestrel server:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
web:
image: webapp:1.0
ports:
- "80:80"
environment:
- ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
```

Kestrel cannot find any static files in the root folder for some reason. It only serves the html files because they are being compiled as razor pages, but no css or js or images. I made a page display the content root folder and the current directory which are both `/app`, plus I went into the container folder and saw that the wwwroot folder was copied into it so I don't understand why it can't find these files?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error and can you add the logs as well? Where you see that error and at which stage?

Comment: when I run `docker-compose up`, I added the full error

Comment: why are you trying to mount in the first place? the content (`wwwroot`) should be included in the artifact produced by the publish command

Comment: You're right, I checked the container directory and the files are there but I can't get kestrel to serve anything besides html files

Comment: @bugbeeb Did you solve it ? plz tell me I am having the same issue ;(

Comment: @amnaw I posted my solution as an answer below

Comment: my files aren't capitalized and can be access thro the browser, but when I copy that working url from the browser to the html img tag, the image doesn't get served ;( see my issue plz if u don't mind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591976/static-files-in-wwwroot-dont-get-rendered-in-docker-container-asp-net-core/70593195?noredirect=1#comment124791401_70593195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot have uppercase file names when running a dotnet application on a Linux machine. Most of my folder and files were capitalized. I don’t know why this happens, it’s quite baffling

Comment: As of today, your statement seems incorrect. I believe Appetere is right now. Please delete this answer since .NET Core no longer seems to behave in the manner you describe. I'm not trying to be rude. I up-voted your question because I found it useful, but I think this answer no longer reflects how .NET Core works in GNU\Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is case-sensitive.  If you request static files with the same case they are stored on disk (regardless of upper or lower case) it should work.